# Admin only access php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to code a page that only allows user with Admin rights (recorded as admin against role in DB). If they are admin then photos are pulled from database for approval. If not admin then they get redirected to admin page and don't see images.

At the moments anyone logged in can view the page and images are displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
<?php

session_start();



$isLoggedIn = isset($_SESSION['first_name']) && isset($_SESSION['username']);
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

if ($isLoggedIn && $_SESSION['username']){


echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['first_name']."<br><a href='login/logged_out.php'>log     
out</a>";

}


$username = $_SESSION['username'];
//var_dump($username);

include("..\connection\connection.php");


// Connect to server and select database.

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 

mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("cannot select DB");

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND role =   
'admin'");

echo(mysql_error());

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);


if ($num_rows =1){                  

include("..\connection\connection.php");

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("cannot select DB");


$photo=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE approved='N'");

echo(mysql_error());

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($photo);//counts the number or rows returned from database   
matching the mysql_query.

if ($numrows==0){

echo "There are no images awaiting approval.";
}


while($get_photo=mysql_fetch_array($photo)){?>

<a href="approve_image_submit.php?images=<?php echo $get_photo['big_images']; ?>"   
target=""><img src="<? echo $get_photo['url']; ?>" title="">


<? } ?>
<?
}else{


die ("You do not have permission to view this page. Redirect to index.phph Click <a  
href='login/login_page.php'>here</a> to log in.");
                //


}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if ($num_rows =1){
```

should be

```
if ($num_rows==1){
```

Comment: Oh yeah. Of course. Thanks. I changed to == but now user with admin rights gets message "You do not have permission to view this page" same as users with non-admin roles.

Comment: Yeah that worked. Also, It looks like it was the path to my connection file not being recognised. When I put in mysql_connect and specified host, etc. it worked.

Answer (score 1):

So may thing are wrong with your script

A. `username` clashing with `database` username 
B. So `$_SESSION` varriables was set
C. Invalid `logic`

I can go on and on

I have help to rewrite the code but you need to replace with relevant information

```
session_start ();
include ("..\connection\connection.php");

$username = @$_SESSION ['username'];
$rowPhoto = array ();
$dbHost = "";
$dbUser = "";
$dbPass = "";
$dbName = "";

if ($_SESSION ['AUTH'] == true && ! isset ( $_SESSION ['username'] )) {
    echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION ['first_name'] . "<br><a href='login/logged_out.php'>log out</a>";
    exit ();
}
$mysqli = new mysqli ( $dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName ); // Replace with relevant information
$result = $mysqli->query ( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND role =  'admin'" );

if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
    $userInfo = $result->fetch_assoc ();
    $photoResult = $mysqli->query ( "SELECT * FROM images WHERE approved='N'" );
    $_SESSION ['AUTH'] = true;
    $_SESSION ['first_name'] = $userInfo ['first_name']; // Replace With
    $_SESSION ['username'] = $username ;
                                                        // Information
    if ($photoResult->num_rows == 0) {
        echo "There are no images awaiting approval.";
    } else {
        $rowPhoto = "";
        while ( $rowPhoto = $photoResult->fetch_assoc () ) {
            echo "<a href=\"approve_image_submit.php?images={$rowPhoto['big_images']}\" target=\"><img src=\"{$rowPhoto['url']}\" title=\"\">";
        }
    }

} else {

    die ( "You do not have permission to view this page. Redirect to index.phph Click <a
            href='login/login_page.php'>here</a> to log in." );
}
```

I hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for that. As you can probably tell I'm still learning fundamentals of PHP. Your code is going to take a little digesting. Thanks

Comment: it ok ... with minor changes .. i think you can get your script working .... let me know if you have additional issues